# Wildfly Swarm and cxf-rt-transports-http

Tags: jboss, cxf, wildfly, wildfly-10, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to convert my project from EAP 6.3 to Wildfly Swarm...

I'm having some trouble with CXF.

I've got the fraction dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then later, I include this, because otherwise I get a `"package org.apache.cxf.message does not exist"` error in my Camel Processor code

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

So if I include it, I get the error:

> Apache CXF library (cxf-core-3.1.9.jar) detected in ws endpoint
>   deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded
>   libraries with container module dependencies or disable the
>   webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper
>   jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach
>   is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices
>   Java EE and any JBossWS specific functionality to be disabled.

Ok, so maybe there's a lib conflict between the camel-cxf modules and my jar... or it's not picking up my jboss-deployment-structure.xml file?

I've tried a few things as suggested by other posts.

I tried adding this to jboss-deployment-structure.xml under ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF and adding the xml file to the webResources of the maven-war-plugin.

```
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="webservices" /> 
    </exclude-subsystems>  
  </deployment>
```

I've also tried adding this to jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
    <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" />
</dependencies>
```

But I keep getting that error.  So I'm not sure how to resolve this conflict.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One Approach is to use Jboss provided CXF libraries and  set `<scope>provided</scope>` for `cxf-rt-transports-http`, so that it compiles and but not package the CXF dependencies .

You find more on [Jboss specific configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html)

Comment: I've tried a lot of things now, and it's still not finding libs. The camel-core.jar is in the uberjar's m2repo, and Eclipse shows it under Maven Dependencies.  But I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for org.apache.camel.*

Comment: Ah. I removed all of the dependencies except camel-cxf, and am not getting the error.  Odd.

Comment: Thats what i was saying, use JBoss provided CXF libraries and not package them  with your application.